# Webpack 5: devtool ValidationError, invalid configuration object

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

While migrating from Webpack 4 to Webpack 5 I got an error when using `devtool` with empty value (only in production mode).

```
module.exports = {
    devtool: isProd ? '' : 'source-map',
    // entry: ...
    // output: ...
    // module: ...
}
```

The message in the console:

```
ValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.devtool should match pattern "^(inline-|hidden-|eval-)?(nosources-)?(cheap-(module-)?)?source-map$".
   BREAKING CHANGE since webpack 5: The devtool option is more strict.
   Please strictly follow the order of the keywords in the pattern.
```

Any ideas how to avoid source maps in production mode? What to type in there?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Answer to own question! Spoiler: `false`.

```
module.exports = {
    devtool: isProd ? false : 'source-map',
}
```

In Webpack 4 it was possible to value this with an empty string. webpack 5 is more strict. [Webpacks devtool configuration](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/).

Comment: What is `isProd ` referencing to?

Comment: It's just a boolean whether the app is in production mode.

Answer (score 3):

somehow my `"source-map"` had a # in it like `"#source-map"` that was causing this error. Solved the error by removing `#` from the string.

**Before:**

```
devtool: (config.enabled.sourceMaps ? '#source-map' : false)
```

**After:**

```
devtool: (config.enabled.sourceMaps ? 'source-map' : false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Before: devtool: "#source-map"
After: devtool: "source-map"